# How is the best way to return an error to ajax request?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, webmethod

When one WebMethod it's called from ajax, if I return a simple string, the ajax code go to success method without errors, something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Hello()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

This is right, but, how is the correct way to make the WebMethod for return a error and this will be captured in ajax Error method instead of success method?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your Response status Code  :

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Hello()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 400 ; // Will be captured on ajax error method 
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Ass simple like this...:D Many Thanks!